# Calculate Java start up cost

Tags: java, time

I currently have a program in which I can print how long it takes to run the main method. When I run this program on command line and time it however, it takes considerably longer.

E.g.,

```
$ time java MyProgram "arg"
done by .004

real    0m0.105s
user    0m0.083s
sys     0m0.022s
```

My question is this- is it possible to calculate the start up cost of the java program within the program itself?

Comment: `main` is called AFTER the JVM itself has initialised, so it will depend on what you consider the "start up" cost to be

Comment: I would like the time from using that command in terminal until the main method starts running. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could put this as the first line in your main method.
`java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getUptime()`