# How to calculate java start up cost

Tags: java

Code:

```
RuntimeMXBean bean = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean();
System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - bean.getStartTime());
System.out.println(bean.getUptime());
```

Result:

```
51
138
```

I wonder why they show different outputs. [source code of getUptime and getStartTime](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/sun/management/RuntimeImpl.java#RuntimeImpl.getUptime%28%29)

Comment: Please include all relevant information in your post. If the link goes stale, the whole question is pointless.

Comment: Maybe there is a difference of a view ms between starting and being up?

Comment: For calculating startup costs see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34259542/calculate-java-start-up-cost) it may help.